# After updating to 4.8 SDK ProGuard minify fails

Tags: dji-sdk

After changing to the SDK 4.8 (all other files remain unchanged) the build fails if minify is enabled.  The error is String-index overflow.

Is there an updated proguard-rules file for 4.8 that takes into account new/changed classes??

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the 4.7 SDK cannot work with the new (default) R8 compressor.
You can get back to a working app by adding the following to the gradle.properties class:

android.enableR8=false

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Mapbox SDK in your application? The issue might be related to pro guard rules. Refer the following [Link to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541770/unable-to-generate-build-with-pro-guard-enabled-using-mapbox-sdk-6-7/53551980#53551980)